Point Sub-domain to Node.js Server
I'm having some trouble getting my Node.js server to show up on my sub-domain. Here's what I've done so far:
I have a Windows VPS running a Node.js server at http://192.168.0.12:443/.
I want this server to be accessible at https://radio.example.net/.
To achieve this, I've pointed an A record for radio.example.net to 192.168.0.12.
Despite setting up the A record, the sub-domain still doesn't seem to connect to my Node.js server. Can someone please help me figure out what I might be doing wrong? Specifically, how do I correctly point the sub-domain to my Node.js server running on Windows? I also opened the ports already, and it is accessible at the IP address but not the domain.
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
I have tried pointing an A record to the IP address, and I have also opened the ports. I'm using Cloudflare for domain hosting if that matters.
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));


server.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 443');
});


What error are you getting when you try to connect?

This sounds like a question about how to use DNS, rather than a question about programming.

@miken32 It depends on what the error is. It might be about configuring Express to recognize the hostname.

Although by default I think it ignores the hostname, you only need to check the name when doing virtual hosting.

Does nslookup correctly translate the subdomain to the IP?

@Barmar Error code 522 is what I get, but usually it just hangs and tries to load but fails. In the browser of course.

@Barmar NS Lookup doesn't translate to the subdomain either

Then it sounds like you didn't actually update your domain's DNS correctly.
